# how to export functions that use non exported function in the same file?

Tags: javascript

I want to import functions that use other non-exported functions and variables that located in the same file
like the following example:

File 1:

```
function foo(number){
    return number + 10;
}
var shoo = 20;
function boo(){
    return foo(1) + shoo;
}
export{boo};
```

File 2:

```
import { boo } from 'File 1';
console.log(boo());
```

hope this example clear

can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use your import in a module script like this

```
<script type="module">
    import { boo } from 'File 1';
    console.log(boo());
</script>
```